# Swift 3 Package Manager Upload to GIT Server

Tags: git, swift3, xcode8, alamofire, swift-package-manager

I want to upload a framework with using other 3rd party dependencies like Alamofire through Swift package manager.

When I try to upload the framework, only the package and the sources are uploaded, not the xcodeproject nor the dependencies.

Another stange thing that, when I clone the project from the server I holds the references but the files are missing.

Comment: Can you specify with Swift Package Manager commands you are using for that task?

Comment: well I used it through Xcode commit and push commands. Is there another way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your `.gitignore` file - it specifies the files that are ignored by git - they are not committed and not pushed to the remote repository. By default, Swift Package Manager generates `.gitignore` file that ignores .build and *.xcodeproj files. If you want to commit these files to git, you should remove the corresponding lines in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Can you elaborate with an example ? and how can I check the  .gitignore files?

Comment: Here is an example of .gitignore: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/blob/master/.gitignore . You can edit your .gitignore file, commit and push it as any other text file.